# Select all PostgreSQL rows where a json column contains a specific key

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Given a PostgreSQL 9.3 table with a json column, how do you write a query that selects all rows where the json column includes a specified key? I'm not interested in the values of the json hash, just whether the object includes the given key.

Comment: In other words, you can do this in later versions of PostgreSQL by casting the data by `data::jsonb ? 'key'`. But I'm interested in PostgreSQL 9.3 specifically.

Comment: Have you tried not casting to `jsonb`. For example: `data ? 'key'`?

Comment: Yeah, the `?` operator does not exist for json columns—only `hstore` and ultimately `jsonb`.

Comment: So is upgrading to the current version to make use of the `?` operator not an option?

Answer (score 4):

If it suits your needs (and you don't store NULL values in your JSON), I think the easiest method is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (data->'key') IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your table has an extra column with the primary key, this should work

```
create table t (i integer primary key, j json, t text);
insert into t values 
(1,'{"id1":"a", "id2":"b"}','xxx'),
(2,'{"id1":"a", "id3":"c"}', null), 
(3,'{"id2":"a", "id4":"b"}', null),
(4,'{"id1":"x", "id6":"v"}','yyy');

select t.* from t join (select i as h,json_object_keys(j) as q from t) k on q='id1' and h=i;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69a72/1

kind of weird, should be a better and more common case solution. I've tried several, no luck